# Is there a easy way to filter mulitfield in django's admin site?

Tags: django, django-admin

The Model:

```
class Person(Model):
  (...)
   fathers = models.ManyToManyField('Person', related_name="fathers_children",  blank=True)
   mothers = models.ManyToManyField('Person', related_name="fathers_children",  blank=True)
   sex = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=1)
```

admin.py:

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  form = PersonAdminForm
  model = Person

  fields = ('last_name', 'birth_date','fathers','mothers')
  ordering = ['last_name','birth_date']

admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)
```

(maybe I cut to much, but I think it is self descriptive)

Please don't think why person can have more than one father/mother - it is intentional.

And now when I enter to e.g /admin/person/836, got the form with two MultipleChoiceFields containing full list of persons.

I want to reduce both - fathers should contains males, mothers - females. But how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply limit the queryset for those fields by overriding the `init` method in the `PersonAdminForm` class:

```
class PersonAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PersonAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['fathers'].queryset = Person.objects.filter(sex='m')
        self.fields['mothers'].queryset = Person.objects.filter(sex='f')
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I need!